# Gujarati fonts not support in console or powershell

Tags: powershell, command-line-interface, momentjs, qunit

I am adding new language support to moment.js called Gujarati, I have written & run all the test using grunt command on power shell & command window, Where some of my test has been failed but I am not able to figure out what is the reason for failure of test due to different values.

The main issue is that i am not able to see proper value on my console or power shell window it's showing only square charter in place of Gujarati character.

for further detail see the attached snap. [image]

Comment: `□` _White Square_ is just a placeholder for character(s) that are not in current console font. Try  running your tests in _PowerShell_Ise_ (and change _Font Family_ to [Unifont](https://czyborra.com/unifont/) if necessary).

Comment: tried that as well.. but no luck

Comment: Gujarati symbols  (for instance, `'ગુજરાતી'`) are rendered properly for me in PowerShell_Ise with FontFamily = Unifont. Windows 8.1, `$PSVersionTable` shows `PSVersion` = `5.0.10586.117`.

Comment: Thx @JosefZ, I solved my main purpose by adding my test to web  page. still I will check ur suggestion once I get back to work. Really appreciate your help.